# What daily cron job generates log summary reports?

Tags: logs

What daily cron job generates log summary reports?

- syslogd
- logrotate
- cron.log
- logwatch
- cron.daily

Comment: For quicker service, tell us the address of your instructor and we'll send them our answers directly.

Answer (score 2):

The system log analyzer and reporter is called **logwatch**. If you have a cron job called logwatch, then it obviously might be the log summary report job. You can run that tool also in the terminal and see the results as output, just type:

```
$ logwatch
```

Answer (score 0):

logwatch generates log summary reports.